# Angular - Explicit annotation required

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running into the following issue with my code:

`Error: [$injector:strictdi] controller is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode`

I've implemented the explicit annotation as seen below, but still can't get it to work.

```
var paymentSummaryTemplate = require('./paymentsummary.html');

function PaymentController($scope, $log, $translate) {
    ...
}

PaymentController.$inject = ['$scope','$log', '$translate'];

p3dng
  .controller('PaymentController', PaymentController)
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/paymentsummary', {
        templateUrl: paymentSummaryTemplate,
        controller: PaymentController,
        controllerAs: 'paymentsummary',
        resolve: getInitData(['campaign', 'event'])
    });
}]);
```

Comment: is this your code, *exactly*?  the `$inject` statement needs to come before the controller definition

Comment: Please use the angular tag for questions regarding Angular 2 and up. The angularjs tag is reserved for questions regarding AngularJS 1.x. It appears as though you're using AngularJS.

Comment: @Claies you should have made that comment your answer!!

Comment: @JoelCDoyle eh, maybe, but this seems like a pretty common thing, and something I remember reading somewhere else;  There isn't really anything special about this question in particular, so I was just halfway clarifying the issue and halfway searching for a duplicate to tag this against.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for suggestion, but that didn't work :(

Comment: this is happening because you have `ng-strict-di` in your HTML.  removing that would *definately* solve the problem, but it doesn't really explain why this isn't passing the strict test in the first place.  And `ng-strict-di` isn't commonly used, so I *would assume* that since it's in place, you know what it's there for and intend to make use of it.  Are you **sure** that this is the controller that it is complaining about?  Is there another controller somewhere in your app?

Comment: Did you try changing `controller: PaymentController` to `controller: "PaymentController"` (written as a string)?

Comment: It looks like there is conflicting controller in the paypal-button module I'm using. Working on getting that resolved.

Thanks everyone for your input.